# Infinitesimals and calculating action for an infinitesimal time interval (path integral formalism in QM, Feynman and Hibbs)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, discrete

I am going through Feynman and Hibb's emended edition of *Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals.*

Going through chapter 2 made me realise I didn't fully understand infinitesimals, I was hoping someone could give some clarification. My current understanding is that an infinitesimal quantity is an infinitely small quantity (allowing for calculus, for example), such that calculations to the first order become exact.

It is stated:

> "The kernel for a particle to go between two points separated by an infinitesimal time interval $\epsilon$ is"
> $$K(i+1, i) = \dfrac{1}{A}\exp \left[ \dfrac{i}{\hbar} \epsilon L \left( \dfrac{x_{i+1}- x_{i}}{\epsilon}, \dfrac{x_{i+1} + x_{i}}{2}, \dfrac{t_{i+1} + t_{i}}{2} \right)\right].\tag{2-34}$$

It is given earlier on that

> $$K(b, a) = \dfrac{1}{A}\sum_{\text{paths from a to b}} \exp\left(\dfrac{i}{\hbar}S[x(t)]\right).$$

I can see that in the above calculation everything has been carried out to first order, and then with the two points being separated by an infinitesimal time, there is only one possible path between the two (straight line in the $x$-$t$ plane).

I am confused, however, as to why means are used for the arguments $x$ and $t$ of the Lagrangian. If we're dealing with infinitesimals, couldn't we just choose either endpoint? How does it make sense to take the mean between a point in time $t_{i}$, and another point $t_{i+1}$ an infinitesimal interval away?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same concept as considering the midpoint approximation in Riemann integral. You consider two fixed points $i+1$ and $i$ and the particle moves directly from point $i$ to $i+1$ in $\epsilon$ time with no intermediate points.

Due to the nature of the discretization we are taking, there is really only one path. Now,  we can evaluate through the elementary amplitude expression:

$$K(b,a) = \frac{1}{A} \exp {i \left( \frac{i}{\hbar} S\left[ x(t) , \dot{x} , t \right] \right)}$$

The question comes what to actually put as velocity, time and position. Velocity, we really only have one way and that is the difference of coordinate between final point and initial divided by time. For time and position, we use the idea of the Riemann midpoint rule.

The idea is discussed in this lecture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZzNf8v1aBg&list=PLPO5pgr_frzTeqa_thbltYjyw8F9ehw7v&index=3&ab_channel=MathandPhysicsBooks)